# Plotly/Dash callbacks called by dcc.Interval get backed up when the interval is more frequent than the time it takes for the callback to complete

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I want to make a callback to update the graph as quickly as is possible. I'm currently using `dcc.Interval(...)`.

It commonly takes 1-3 seconds for the callback to compete (it updates the graph).

If I set `dcc.Interval(id='myid', interval=1000)` then the callbacks happen too fast and the graph basically hangs. It seems that each subsequent callback interrupts the rendering in progress and things seize up.

My goal is simply to run the callback as often as possible. That means different timing depending on network conditions, and I don't want to set the interval to the lowest common denominator.

Plotly is pretty keen on avoiding circular dependencies, so there isn't an obvious way to do an infinite loop with callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

A plotly forum post addresses this question:

https://community.plotly.com/t/prevent-re-entrant-callbacks/17393

In summary, it uses the plotly exception `PreventUpdate` and [shared locks](https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks) to identify when a callback is being started before the previous callback finished running.

There's a short discussion in that forum post regarding this not being a great use case Plotly/Dash.